# How to get input text and content to same height inside a table?

Tags: css, forms, html-table, css-float

I'm trying to get a the text of an input next to a descriptive text by floating these two elements. While trying it with float the descriptives text-baseline is higher than the inputs one. You can see it the best if you put a dash into the input.

Nevertheless I can see that the text inside the input is getting transformed somehow though using the same text/font criteria as for the descriptive part. It's quite narrower.

Is there anybody out there [who can help me]?

```css
.form_table {
width: 100%;
max-width: 600px;
height: 100%;
max-height: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
p{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
text-align: left;
}
input {
border: 0px solid black;
width: 100%;
font-family: Helvetica, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Calibri, "Myriad Pro", Verdana, "Trebuchet MS", "sans-serif"; 
font-size: 18px;
background-color: none;
}
.form_th {
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 2px;
font-family: Helvetica, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Calibri, "Myriad Pro", Verdana, "Trebuchet MS", "sans-serif";
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: normal;
}
.output {
text-align: left;
float: left; 
width: 20%;
white-space: nowrap;
}
.input {
float: right;
width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<form>
<table class="form_table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="form_th"><div class="output">Insert a dash_
</div>
<div class="input">
<p><input></p>
</div></th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Instead of `float`, use `display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;` ... and remove the `<p>` that wraps the `input`. That is not what a `<p>` is for.

Comment: Ok, you're right, the text appears on the same height now (had to change the width values), but how do I get the text to the left side? `text-align:left` doesn't seem to be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood u change In CSS ( input tag ) font-size to 25px;

```css
p{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
font-size: 24px;
}
input {
border: 0px solid black;
width: 100%;
background-color: none;
font-family: "Times New Roman", "Minion Pro", "sans-serif";
 /* add this font size */
 font-size:25px;
}
.command {
text-align: left;
float: left; 
}
.input {
float: left;
text-align: left;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
font-family: "Times New Roman", "Minion Pro", "sans-serif";
font-size= 30px;

}
```

```html
<form>
<section>
<div class="command">
<p>Insert_</p>
</div>
<div class="input">
<p><input type="text"></p>
</div>
</section>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, I've just excessively edited the code and question. However your solution doesn't work and isn't what I'm looking for. Just changing the fonts size to get the optical same height is also just working for the font you're using. I'm looking for a solution which solves the problem in general. Moreover on my display your solution looks even worse...

Answer (score 0):

@LGSon brought me on the right path.

> Instead of float, use `display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;`

However, the text then appeared centered although I wanted it aligned left so I put another div-container around this fun an set `align: left`. Same works for setting `align: left` to the table-header.

Final solution right here:

```css
.form_table {
width: 100%;
max-width: 600px;
height: 100%;
max-height: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
p{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
text-align: left;
}
input {
border: 0px solid black;
width: 100%;
font-family: Helvetica, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Calibri, "Myriad Pro", Verdana, "Trebuchet MS", "sans-serif"; 
font-size: 18px;
background-color: none;
}
.form_th {
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 2px;
font-family: Helvetica, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Calibri, "Myriad Pro", Verdana, "Trebuchet MS", "sans-serif";
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: normal;
}
.output {
text-align: left;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 20%;
white-space: nowrap;
}
.input {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<form>
<table class="form_table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="form_th"><div align="left">
<div class="output">Insert a dash_
</div>
<div class="input">
<input>
</div>
</div></th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</form>
```